# Can I force a Camel routing app to produce JMS BytesMessages but with text content?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

I'm working with a Camel application that is taking messages from one JMS queue and writing them to another JMS queue.

The output messages are JMS `TextMessages` which are not quite preferred for this particular JMS broker. I've determined for this product, and for the downstream (non-JMS) consumers, we'd like Camel to produce `javax.jms.BytesMessages`, but populate their data as a string via `Message.writeUTF(String)`.

I have found that the Spring JMSConfiguration does allow me to set a property `jmsMessageType="Bytes"` which gets me halfway there, but is there any other configuration to make it write my String payload via `writeUTF`? Currently it appears to be encoding the string down to a byte array then setting it via `BytesMessage.writeBytes(byte[])`.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation how to use a custom message converter
http://camel.apache.org/jms

Then you can do the mapping to JMS Message yourself and use the writeUTF method